# Jquery Form Plug in, how to change value in target

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var options = { 
    target:     '.postBoxAjax', 
    url:        'sub/function.php', 
    success: SubmitSuccesful
}; 


$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);

</script>
```

Is it possible for me to add html tag to the target?

I want to make a input box where a visitor can submit an image url, and it will display the image once they submit the link without refresh. Currently, the code will only display the image url in .postBoxAjax, I would like to add:

```
<img src="taget value" width="580"/>
```

to wrap the target value, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do an AJAX call to update your page. You just need to get the value of the input in a particular location, and place its value into an image.
at the most basic level, you want to do something along these lines

```
$(document).append("<img src=\""+ $("input")[0].value +"\" width=\"580\"/>");
```

Put this in a function and call it from your submit button's onclick event. It will take the first input on your page and dump its value into an image. Be aware that you should scrub your input before injecting its value onto your page, as this is a risk for a javascript injection attack.

Comment: sorry, i am really new for the jquery stuff, How can i get the value from target?? and if i have two input box, how can i get both value in jquery??

Comment: target:     '.postBoxAjax'
how can i put the value of "target" into the $(document).append();

sorry for my poor English, I will need to get the value from the target first, then put it into append. so how can i get this value??

Comment: the class .postBoxAjax is not unique, so I am making the assumption that there is only one of these on your page. To get the value of an input element with this class, use $(".postBoxAjax")[0].value .
alternatively, you could use $(options.target)[0].value following your code above, thought I find that code less easy to follow.